# Deserialise a generic class , with unknown generic type - Jackson

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

```
public class MessageModel<T> {
    T body;
}
```

Now `T` could be object of type say `Cricket` or `Football`. Now this class is serialised and published to a queue.
While consuming, what is the best way to deserialise and identify the message type as Cricket or Football, so that the corresponding service is called. I am using jackson to serialise.

I tried introducing a new property `Type` during serialisation and during deserialisation will first read as json object, identify the Type and again use jackson to deserialise as the type is known.
Ex:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
String messageType = jsonObject.optString("message_type");
objectMapper.readValue(message,new TypeReference<MessageModel<messageType>>(){});
```

But looking for better approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *While consuming, what is the best way to deserialise and identify the message type as Cricket or Football, so that the corresponding service is called.*

This isn't possible. Generics don't work that way.

Generics are involved only at compile-time. When your program runs, the type information from generics is no longer present. There is great information and examples in the [Java Tutorial on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

As a brief example, here are two simple classes:

```
class MessageModel<T> {
}

class Cricket {
}
```

If we create a new `MessageModel<Cricket>`, it compiles and runs fine.

```
MessageModel<Cricket> cricket = new MessageModel<>();
```

But at runtime, `cricket` is identified only as an instance of `MessageModel` – there is no evidence that the `Cricket` class was associated in any way. As a bit of evidence, asking the `cricket` object to report its own class at runtime it will print itself as `MessageModel`:

```
System.out.println("runtime: " + cricket.getClass());

runtime: class MessageModel
```

This behavior is within a single JVM, but nothing changes if your program serializes an object and sends it to some other program. That other program also has no ability to determine the original `Cricket` generic type from the serialized object.

---

If you need the original class later, you could do something like below, capturing the original class at object construction. Later, when the receiving program needs to know `Cricket` was the original class, it can call `getConcreteClass()`:

First, modify `MessageModel`: require a `Class` at object construction, save that class as a private member, add `getConcreteClass()` to expose it:

```
class MessageModel<T> {
    private final Class concreteClass;

    MessageModel(Class concreteClass) {
        this.concreteClass = concreteClass;
    }

    public Class getConcreteClass() {
        return concreteClass;
    }
}
```

From there, the original class is avaiable at runtime:

```
MessageModel<Cricket> cricket = new MessageModel<>(Cricket.class);
System.out.println("getClass()         : " + cricket.getClass());
System.out.println("getConcreteClass() : " + cricket.getConcreteClass());

getClass()         : class MessageModel
getConcreteClass() : class Cricket
```